# Chamada em Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou implementando um `html` de um sistema utlizando o [php](/questions/tagged/php) e também estou realizando uma chamada em `ajax` para abrir uma página qualquer, mas, quando retorna a minha `url`, a mesma não lê o `include` da página.

Exemplo:

**A página html:** 'teste.php'

```
<?php include('inc_header.php'); ?>

<section class="content">
</section>

<?php include('inc_rodape.php'); ?>
```

**A chamada que fiz, foi essa:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "teste.php",
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(openHtml){
        $('.content').html(openHtml);
    }   
});
```

A página `teste.php` abre normal, mas não lê o topo. Essa classe *`.content`* é um efeito que faz antes de abrir a página `teste.php`, essa parte tá funcionando corretamente, só esse `include` header que não funciona.

Qual seria a solução desse problema?

Comment: Déa, parece-me um problema de `path`. Consegue abrir a página `teste.php` directamente no browser?

Comment: Oi Sergio, abro normalmente!! :(

Comment: Déa, tem algum `echo` no php? porque se quer carregar o ficheiro então ele precisa de "correr" primeiro para mandar para o pedido ajax

Comment: Não tem nenhum echo! Não entendi o que você falou

Comment: Já tentou como o `.load()`? Assim: `$('.content').load("teste.php")`. Substituíndo o `$.ajax()` todo.

Comment: O que tem dentro desse include do header?

Comment: bfavaretto, tem o topo do sistema web(cabeçalho para ser mais especifica)

Comment: Tentei, Marcelo! Nada para nada

Comment: Está difícil diagnosticar o problema. Você conseguiria disponibilizar seu teste em algum endereço acessível? Ou criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o problema?

Comment: De fato, 
O Script parece correto, poderia postar o erro do Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor na requisição HTTP para vermos o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo de utilização Ajax com PHP.

Código:

**inc_header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Carregamento de Pagina em Ajax</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".content").load("inc_meio.php");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="content">
```

**inc_rodape.php**

```
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**inc_meio.php**

```
  <?php
      // pode conter programação também ...
     echo date("d/m/Y");
     echo "<br />";
   ?>
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
    carregando com ajax<Br />
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include 'inc_header.php';
    include 'inc_rodape.php';
```

**Funcionamento**

Na inc_header.php tem um script assim

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".content").load("inc_meio.php");
});
```

que é o responsável em carregar com ajax o `inc_meio.php`. Ao chamar `index.php`, ela vai incluir o `inc_header.php` e o `inc_rodape.php`, ficando como dinâmico `inc_meio.php` ou qualquer outra página que preferir

Nesse [link](https://api.jquery.com/load/), tem vários exemplos com load. Também tem o [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) e o principal o [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) no site [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

**Página Renderizada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aonde tem uma flecha foi renderizado via ajax ([jQuery.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)), você deve sempre renderizar partes e fixar algumas.

Comment: Olha os negativando ... !!! quem será hiem!

Comment: certo, entendi! Não tá rolando dessa forma, deve ser alguma restrição de scripts, eu dou um console e não me retorna o erro.